# keep data on reload Angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, state-management

Im using `behaviourSubject` `RXJS`, for interaction between component, I got 3 components, where

- **inquiry form**

  user enter id number to check summon, get summon and send to inquiry response
- **inquiry response**

  get summon from inquiry response and display summon in form of checkbox, then send selected summon (total amount) to payment component
- **payment component**

  get total summon from inquiry response and display it.

but the problem is when user reload the page on **payment component** data get from `Behaviour Subject` is empty, based on my finding, I found solution using `localStorage`, but its not applicable to me, also found about another state management library like `ngrx`, I am in middle of project, hard to me for implement, is there any better practice to solve this problem ?

this is what I had tried:

**payment-store.service.ts**

```
  private transactions = new BehaviorSubject<any>({});
  public transactions$ = this.transactions.asObservable();

    setTransaction(data) {
    this.transactions.next(data);
  }
```

**payment-component.ts**

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.paymentStore.transactions$.subscribe(
      response => {
        this.totalSummon = response;
      }
    );
  }
```

and this is my full [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yb36jc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fpayment%2Fpayment.component.ts). I could use some suggestion and solution to solve this.

Comment: Why is localstorage not an option?

Comment: well one way is to log selected summon in database and retrieve it on the page load and  compute the amount again. instead of sending the  amount to payment component you could pass the id of the log which can be used to load the data on page load

Comment: @Chrillewoodz because user can edit localStorage

Comment: What do you mean "when user reload the page"? Like, pressing *reload* button or *F5*? If so, Angular app can't store the state. For data to persist you can use storage (either local or session) API or store them server side. I guess cookies would be an option, too.

Comment: well, the user can modify your application data anyway. while it's running. how can it benefit them to edit local storage (or session storage for example)?

Comment: can you explain more ? @NormundsKalnberzins how user can modify my application data ?

Comment: there is not a one universal answer, but as the user can execute code say from developer console, depending on what your code is exposing or what events it generates/consumes user can interfere. If there is sufficient incentive, someone will do it.

Comment: or plain straightforward - say in Chrome - put a breakpoint, once stopped, override any variable in scope and continue.

Answer (score 1):

If storing the data locally isn't a solution then the easiest solution would be to store it in a database. Preferably one that doesn't require you to set up a backend on your own.

Firebase would provide a fast implementation for you as it only requires an initial setup and writing a few security rules so the correct user can access the data.

If you've never used Firebase before I would suggest having a look at `@angular/fire` which is the implementation for Angular. You can find its documentation here:

https://github.com/angular/angularfire2

With some example documents to get you started.